# ExtJS Spring file upload

Tags: extjs, file-upload, extjs3

I have ext form panel which includes file upload item. Code is shown below:

```
fp = new Ext.FormPanel({
         fileUpload: true,
         autoHeight: true,
         bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;',
         labelWidth: 50,
         defaults: {
             anchor: '95%',
             allowBlank: false,
             msgTarget: 'side'
         },
         items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                id: 'form-file',
                emptyText: 'Select excel file',
                fieldLabel: 'File',
                name: 'file',
                buttonText: 'Choose File',
                buttonCfg: {
                    iconCls: 'upload-icon'
                }
            }
         ],
         buttons: [{
            text: 'Load',
             handler: function(){                   
                if(fp.getForm().isValid()){
                  fp.getForm().submit({
                      url: myURL,
                      waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                      success: function(fp, o){
                        // I want to get loaded excel data list
                      },
                      failure : function(fp,o)
                      {
                        console.log('error');
                      }
                  });
                 }
             }
         }]
     });
```

I have spring controller and some services for manipulating uploaded excel data. After I upload excel, I iterate data over excel and put them in a list.

```
@RequestMapping("/uploadExcel")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, ? extends Object> uploadExcellData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
{
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    try
    {
        result = uploadService(file);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    return result;
}

public Map<String,Object> uploadService(MultipartFile argFile) throws BLOException, DAOException 
{
    Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<String,Object>(3);

    List importExcelList = null;
    try 
    {
        if (!argFile.isEmpty()) 
        {   
            importExcelList = parseExcelAndCreateListFunction(argFile.getInputStream());

            result.put("total", new Integer(importExcelList.size()));
            result.put("success", true);

            result.put("data", importExcelList);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I run this code, I got "`NetworkError: 404 Not Found`".
I want to return excel data list after form submit. I couldn't do this. How can I get excel data list on submit callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated java file like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/uploadExcel")
@ResponseBody
public void uploadExcellData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    try
    {
        result = uploadService(file);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write("{success:true, total:'"+result.size()+"', data:'"+result+"'}");

}

public List uploadService(MultipartFile argFile) throws BLOException, DAOException 
{
    List importExcelList = null;
    try 
    {
        if (!argFile.isEmpty()) 
        {   
            importExcelList = parseExcelAndCreateListFunction(argFile.getInputStream());
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return importExcelList;
}
```

And also I have updated my js file like this:

```
fp = new Ext.FormPanel({
   fileUpload: true,
   autoHeight: true,
   bodyStyle: 'padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;',
   labelWidth: 50,
   defaults: {
       anchor: '95%',
       allowBlank: false,
       msgTarget: 'side'
   },
   items: [
      {
          xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
          id: 'form-file',
          emptyText: 'Select excel file',
          fieldLabel: 'File',
          name: 'file',
          buttonText: 'Choose File',
          buttonCfg: {
              iconCls: 'upload-icon'
          }
      }
   ],
   buttons: [{
      text: 'Load',
       handler: function(){                   
          if(fp.getForm().isValid()){
            fp.getForm().submit({
                url: myURL,
                waitMsg: 'Uploading your photo...',
                success: function(fp, o){
                    var resData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(o.result.data);
                    // I can iterate resData
                },
                failure : function(fp,o)
                {
                    Ext.MessageBox.alert("Failure", "your error message");
                }
            });
           }
       }
   }]
});
```

I solved my problem as I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need return additional parameter and check in `success` method `action` parameter. Please check [Extjs Docs (action.result)](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.BasicForm-method-doAction).

Comment: What you mean about additional parameter? Where and what can I put additional parameter?

Comment: So in your code in `success` method you receive two params: `fp, o` so - you can check in firebug `o.result` - I think there you'll see `data`.

Comment: I couldn't reach `success` method, yet. I am getting `NetworkError` after I upload and iterate file.

Comment: I.e. error is in the js side, right? And it goes to `failure` method? What do you see in firebug?

Comment: Yes error in the js side. Not goes to `failure` method. When it returns from controller it gives `404 NetworkError`. I debugged and I got something different, it puts `<pre>` tag to the return value, I think it cause error, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: So 404 error means that page not found (or you return such header from your server side). The issue is on server, you can create very simple page which will return correct result (can't help you, cause I'm working with php only)... Also I think you can create a screenshot and attach link to it here to understand your issue more deeply.